# Easiest way to pay a large amount of money when traveling to the US in one transaction?

Tags: usa

When traveling to the US, how do we pay for more than $25,000 in one transaction? For example, for university tuition fees. I can use my bank debit card to take out some cash at the ATM, but I guess it doesn't work on cases like this.

Comment: Even for fees within the limit of an ATM, you still wouldn't want to bother getting cash first, just present the card to the university bursar's office.  Unless they charge some ridiculous processing fee (over 1%), in which case that's a warning sign that they don't actually care about their students.   For larger amounts, methods of payment should be clearly described on the university website.  Anyway, the methods available will depend on the payee, so you will get much better information directly from them than asking here.

Comment: Wire transfer is probably the most common.

Comment: it's not actually specific for paying university, can be any kind of transaction. What are other viable options? For wire transfer, I might not have someone available at my home country to do it for me.

Comment: It depends not only on und lthe payee but also on the source of the money.  Is it in a bank account (in which case you probably don't need "someone in your home country") or in the form of cash under the mattress?

Comment: @phoog it's in a bank account in my country. currently I dont have a US bank account. So if I were to wire the money myself, I have to go to US, make a bank account, go back home, wire the money, and then go back to US again. or is there any other way?

Comment: I think what was meant is transfer the money directly to the recipient. Ask for account number, routing code and BIC. Even if you have the money on your account, you might not be able to pay that much with a debit card.

Comment: @Rei My bank does not require me to be personally present to initiate a wire transfer.  If I needed to wire money to myself in another country, I could order the transfer without traveling back to the country where the account is located.

Answer (score 2):

> When traveling to the US, how do we pay for more than $25,000 in one
>   transaction?

You pay it the way acceptable to the transaction recipient, who usually lists them. Depending on institution it could be:

- A wire transfer;
- A cashier's check from your bank (did this myself with a much larger amount);
- A debet or credit card (could be with or without a fee);
- ACH transfer (kind of debet-to-debet US bank transfer);
- Cash or personal checks (both are accepted for tax payments, for example, although cash is obviously less convenient because you couldn't mail it).

Finally if your preferred/easiest way to pay is not listed, you can always ask.